# Not able to access JSON file in Sitecore web root folder

Tags: iis

I have added a JSON file **veevaweb2pdf.sitemap.json** and a text file **veevaweb2pdf.txt** for a third-party plug-in. I am able to access the text file but not JSON file in all UAT, Staging and Production Environments which is working fine in my local machine.

**Accessing Text file**: http://mydomain/veevaweb2pdf.txt - **Worked**

**Accessing JSON file**: http://mydomain/veevaweb2pdf.sitemap.json - **Not working.** Getting below error

**The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**

Comment: Is it a static file on your drive?

Comment: @MarekMusielak, Yes, manually uploaded file

Comment: JSON extension needs to be mapped. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/africaapps/2013/06/07/how-to-serve-static-json-files-from-a-windows-azure-website/

Comment: @MarkCassidy, As suggested, I modified web.config of Sitecore through FTP to include .json extension in staticContent section but still not working. Is there anything that I am missing?